# Python: Send cookie with urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2, cookielib

I need is to send the value of a cookie to a web eg *google.com*.

I've tried cookielib, but by asking **"headers"** cookie does not leave me . How can I send?

Answer (score 0):

As far is I know, the only way to do this is to build a custom URL opener and include HTTPCookieProcessor in its list of handlers.

It is possible to override the default handler or to simply define your own urlopen() that uses the cookie jar

```
cookiejar = cookielib.CookieJar()
cookie_handler = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar)
# build_opener() automatically adds default handlers up front
opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie_handler)

# override global opener
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# alternative version that does not override the global opener
def myurlopen(url, data=None):
  req = urllib2.Request(url)
  return opener.open(req, data)

# add a custom cookie
cookie = cookielib.Cookie(
   None,                 # version
   'Header', 'value',    # name, value
   port, False,          # port, port_specified
   'example.org', True, False  # domain, domain_specified, domain_initial_dot
   '/', True,            # path, path_specified
   False,                # secure (needs https)
   None,                 # expires
   False,                # discard
   None, None,           # comment, comment_url
   False                 # rest
)
cookiejar.set_cookie(cookie)
```

Comment: And where I place the value of the cookie?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You might need some experimentation with creation of the cookie. The 17-arg constructor is certainly not "simple" any more.